# General term for a finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Define a sequence $(u_k)$  by

$u_0=0$,$u_k=({k+2 \over k})u_{k-1}+{1 \over k}$.

Find $u_n$.

I couldn't get an idea on how to even start. But to help the community, the sequence goes like this starting from $u_0$.

$0,1,2.5,4.5,7,10,13.5,17.5$

Thanks.

Comment: CAS gives: $u(k)=\frac{1}{4} \left(3 k+k^2\right)$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk what is CAS ?

Comment: CAS like:Mathematica,Maple. See for more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system. List of computer algebra systems : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk  great. Can it be done without a computer?

Comment: Of course , can do it without a computer.

Comment: $u_1$ should be 1, not 2.5, since $u_1=(\frac{1+2}{1})u_0+\frac{1}{1}=2\cdot0+1$. Which is good, because that matches what Mariusz' formula gives for $k=1$.

Comment: @FrancisAdams oops sorry. Will edit that

Answer (score 0):

One standard approach to find out information about sequences is by calculating their differences 
$$\Delta^k u_n = \Delta^{k-1} u_{n+1} - \Delta^{k-1}u_{n}\qquad,\qquad \Delta u_n = u_{n+1} - u_n$$. If we have $\Delta^{k} u_n =0$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$ (for all n), then the sequence is a polynomial  of degree $k-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Write a few first members according to the difference equation until you see the pattern, ie. $u_1 = 4/2+1/2, u_2 = 5/3 (4/2+1/2)+1/3$, say until $u_5$ or $u_6$. After some not hard  manipulation you get an expression for the general term
$$
u_k = (k+2)(k+1)\left[ \frac1{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3} + \frac1{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4} + \dots + \frac1{k \cdot (k+1) \cdot (k+2)} \right].
$$
Now use the following identity (which you get via standard decomposition to elementary fractions)
$$
\frac1{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac12 \frac1n - \frac1{n+1} + \frac12 \frac1{n+2}
$$
to get kind of telescopic sum in the brackets above - after a few elementary modifications you get
$$
\left[ \frac1{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3} + \frac1{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4} + \dots + \frac1{k \cdot (k+1) \cdot (k+2)} \right] = \frac{k^2 + 3k}{4(k+1)(k+2)}
$$
which finally yields
$$
u_k = \frac{k^2 + 3k}4.
$$